# Open webcam and set as background (question)

Tags: java, swing, background, camera, jframe

Best reader,

I'm stuck on one of my concepts.
I'm making a program which classroom children can measure themselves with.
This is what the program includes;
 - 1 webcam (only used for a simple webcam view.)
 - 2 phidgets (don't mind these.)

So, this was my plan. I'll draw a rectangle on the webcamview and make it repaint itself constantly.
When the repainting is stopped by one of the phidgets, the rectangle's value will be returned in centimeters or meters.

I've already written the code of the rectangle that's repainting itself and this was my result:

(It's a roundRectangle, the lines are kind of hard to see in this image, sorry about that.)
[image]

As you can see, the background is now simply black. 
I want to set the background of this JFrame as a webcam view (if possible) and then draw the
rectangle over the webcam view instead of the black background.

I've already looked into jmf, fmj and such but am getting errors even after checking my webcam path and adding the needed jar libraries. So I want to try other options.

So;
 - I simply want to open my webcam, use it as background (yes live stream, if possible in some way).
   And then draw this rectangle over it.
I'm thus wondering if this is possible, or if there's other options for me to achieve this.

Hope you understand my situation, and please ask if anything's unclear.

EDIT:
I got my camera to open now trough java. The running camera is of type "Process".
This is where I got the code for my camera to open: http://www.linglom.com/2007/06/06/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/
I adjusted mine a little so it'll open my camera instead.
But now I'm wondering; is it possible to set a process as background of a JFrame?
Or can I somehow add the process to a JPanel and then add it to a JFrame?
I've tried several things without any succes.

My program as it is now, when I run it, opens the measuring frame and the camera view seperatly.
But the goal is to fuse them and make the repainting-rectangle paint over the camera view.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+webcam

Comment: I've actually seen most of those already, and tried out a few.
But, as I were saying; I want to try other options.

At least I'd like to know how I could open my own webcam preview view, or how to open any application trough java.

Comment: Just a note saying "running the camera as a Process" is quite probably not the way to go.. This just runs an external application through Java, comparative to running an application from a shell or command line. You'll have to look into ways to capture the camera output instead is what I recon.

Comment: True, but I really don't know how I can manage this.
I'd like some help on that.

Comment: I'm not sure but, a frame's background can only be a "Color."'s?

Comment: Last resorts:

If you have a way to control the location of the image from the external process, paint your `JFrame` on top of it.

Heck, you could even place them both manually on your screen :)

Oh, and you can put static images as background, if you use layered panels or override the component's paint().

Comment: A little bit of an crazy idea will be the following.
If you are able to open the webcam stream with videolanclient or windows media player, then there is a comfortable way to show the video stream in a swing frame with the help of DJNative http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html 
If you need further help feel free to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a matter of setting a webcam stream as the *background* for your interface.  More likely, you need to create a media player component, add it to your GUI, and then overlay your rectangles on top of that component.

As you probably know from searching for Java webcam solutions in Stack Overflow already, it's not easy, but hopefully the [JMF Specs and API Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/specdownload-136569.html) will help you through it.  The API guide is a PDF and has sections on receiving media streams, as well as sample code.